# Software for BMW algebra calculations?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, knot-theory, computer-algebra, mathematical-software

Does software exist for computations in the BMW algebra?

For example, I'd like to be able to express elements in a basis of "totally descending tangles" as in a paper of Morton–Wassermann. At present, I'm pretty naive and wouldn't even know how to specify and manipulate tangles.

It would also suffice to use some algebraically specified basis of reduced words in the generators.

Comment: There is something in **sage** about diagram algebras, but it does not seem to include the BMW algebras (see sage: `sage.combinat.diagram_algebras`)

Comment: Sage does have Brauer algebras (implemented as subalgebras of partition algebras).